# New install of mythbuntu 12.04.3 disk size reported only 500GB but is 4TB

Tags: installation, mythbuntu, mythtv

Trying to install mythbuntu 64bit to new seagate 4TB drive. The install only reports drive as 500 GB? Also if I let the install do auto install it fails at installing the grub. It seemed to work when I created two partitions but then doesn't boot into mythtv when restarted. What am I doing wrong? Is there a guide on the install itself for noobs?
Have xtreamer ultra 2 which had older version but hard disk failed.
Thanks,
Hugh

Answer (score 1):

You must use GPT partition table for disks that are larger then 2 TB.

WARNING: 
This steps will erase all content from the drive.

1. Run LiveCD.
2. Open GParted
3. Select "Create new partition table" from menu "Device".
4. Click on advanced settings.
5. Select GPT and click on "Create".

Now you can install Ubuntu using the installer!

Comment: I downloaded gparted and created 3 partitions /root /swap /boot 20GB,4GB, and 3.?TB. After running the mythbuntu install still reports drive as 500 GB. Reformatting drive for third time. Very frustrated. mythbuntu install reports different partition sizes to gparted/gnome.

Comment: Do you see whole drive in GParted? And another question - /boot partition is unuseful nowdays, do you need it?

Comment: Yes see whole drive in gparted but can't mount the drive. Formatted to ext3 and ext4 but the mythbuntu install only reports 500GB. Have swaped my computer backup drive (2TB) and installed mythbuntu on that. Can't figure out the 4TB drive, it's now my backup for my computer until I get more time or a fix is provided. Thanks for your help.